# Binding an ObservableCollection to an ItemsControl - not as simple as it sounds?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection, itemscontrol

This has been very difficult to track down and has caused me a great deal of pain - but it seems `ItemsControls` do not behave the way I would expect. It almost seems like a bug in WPF - but being new to WPF I'm erring on the side of it's my fault, not theirs.

To reproduce it is very simple - bind an `ItemsControl` to an `ObservableCollection`, and then replace an item in the collection. It's so simple I cannot believe Google doesn't find thousands of people with the same problem.

The code below simply binds an `ItemsControl` to an `ObservableCollection` of `Brush`. Change a brush (by clicking the button), and you get a couple of data errors as the rectangle's brush binding is momentarily of the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl` (!), rather than of the new item. This momentary crash of bindings has caused my application to take over half a second to update when run in the debugger whenever I replace an (immutable, regular CLR object) item in the collection - what am I doing wrong?

```xml
<Window x:Class="Dummy.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Brush}">
                    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="SwitchClick">Switch</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Dummy
{
    public partial class Test : Window
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<Brush> foos = new ObservableCollection<Brush>();
        public ObservableCollection<Brush> Foos { get { return foos; } }
        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Foos.Add(Brushes.Green);
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void SwitchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Foos[0] = Foos[0] == Brushes.Green ? Brushes.Silver : Brushes.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what .NET version you're using? I'm on 3.5, VS2008.

Comment: Thank you.. sounds like it is a bug then. Great, up to now I'd been assuming everything was my fault, my misuse, and up to now I've been right holding that belief. Now my faith is shattered ;). I'll have to do a Remove/Insert workaround... unfortunately, this is only part of my problems with this control... and the larger problem seems to also be "their" fault =(. Sigh.

Comment: Ahmmm not sure yet but can i look at the namespace that you are using in the window

Comment: Do you have .net framework 4 present on your pc?

Comment: Sample now includes all code - it's being run in it's own project with no other code. Framework 4 is installed, yes. Using VS2008 I cannot target it however.

Comment: <Window x:Class="Wpf4_Unleashed.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" MinWidth="762" Width="Auto" SizeToContent="Width"> can you please try this :)

Comment: If I change the xmlns it doesn't compile as it can no longer find any controls. Changing the other properties, Width, SizeToContent, Title etc does not resolve the issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5118/discussion-between-mania-and-allan-chua)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahmm After trying it in my unit which uses .NET 4.0 and it worked out I think this is a problem in .NET 3.5. If you're clients are insisting to use it in .NET 3.5 Version advice them to upgrade to .NET 4.0 and this problem shall be closed. thanks :)